# UIView Not Resizing On Roation When Using Autosizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autoresizingmask

I have an app that starts in Landscape mode and I have the following UIView that is created to go full screen.

```
- (void)loadSignupScreen {

CGFloat screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
CGFloat screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;

self.signupContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.signupContainer setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];

UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
[bgImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[bgImageView setAlpha:0.8];


[self.signupContainer addSubview:bgImageView];
[self.view addSubview:self.signupContainer];
```

}

The problem is that when I rotate the screen to portrait it isn't full screen instead it only seems to be about 3/4 the length of the screen. How can I make it fill the screen on rotate? I don't have a problem using the autosizing in IB just when it is programmed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the wrong `autoresizingMask` to the `signupContainer`. It should just be flexible height and width.

```
[self.signupContainer setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Also the `UIImageView` needs an `autoresizingMask`.

```
UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
[bgImageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong. My first guess would be your view controller is not in the responder chain correctly, or you are missing a call to `super` in your view controller method implementations.

Comment: Thanks, I also forgot to autoresize the "bgImageView" so that didn't expand to the size of the containing view.